# How I can load application.properties into test class for getting the spring.profiles.active value?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I'm writing integration test which should works only with the specific profile. The problem is that I should get profile name from spring.profiles.active value in application.properties file. But I always get null due to real value from application.properties.

I've created for main method which explicitly put value into System.properties:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
}
    @Autowired
   public MyApplication(Environment environment) {
      String property = "spring.profiles.active";
      System.getProperties().setProperty(property, environment.getProperty(property));
   }
```

But the value still is null. 
In the test class I use following annotations:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyApplication.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes=MyApplication.class)
```

For loading context from the main class where I manually set the necessary value.
Also tried use `@TestPropertySource("classpath:application.properties")`
But nothing help. And I can't hardcode the value. It's should be get only from application.properties

**UPDATE**
It was my mistake. I've tried getValue from static method :/
Maybe someone know how I can disable class test by use this value?
The @IfProfileValue still return null and therefore doesn't fit.

**UPDATE**
I've realized that disabling is useless and better just use appropriate config using @SpringBootTest(classes=AppropriateConfigClass.class)

I'll choose **gargkshitiz** answer as solved, because he was the only one who tried to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are halfway there. `@TestPropertySource` reads from `src/test/resources`. Add `src/test/resources/application.properties` with overridden values and you should be done.

Answer (score 1):

Answer by @gargkshitiz is perfect !

In case you have only property `spring.profiles.active` to be read then you can mention it following way(it will save us from maintaining properties file).

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
                value={"spring.profiles.active=yourActiveProfileName"})
```

Also you can specify multiple properties,

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
                value={"spring.profiles.active=yourActiveProfileName",
                       "spring.some.other.property=propertyValue"})
```

You can drop `webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT` if you don't need it.